# Need help identifying Korean-made bass

Tags: bass-guitar

I am a work buddy who is in wants to sell a bass that he bought while stationed in Korea.  Unfortunately there are no brand markings on it, and I have been unable to identify it by its body or headstock shape.

It feels very well made, and as you can see from the pictures, has a neck-through design.  It also has active EQ and a gorgeous sound.  Do any of you out there have any idea what this might be?

[image: Front view]

[image: Back view]

Comment: Looks like a Tune of some kind

Comment: Looks like a quality made bass! I'd have been proud to put my name on it if I'd made it! Check in the body cavities for any clues. Somewhat reminiscent of the SGC Nanyo Bass Collections of the '80s/'90s. Perhaps a prototype they made?

Comment: What year do you think it was made? How much did it cost? New/second hand?

Comment: @bigbadmouse - have you tried googling 'tune bass guitar'..? Maybe in about 3 weeks time - beginning of April...

Comment: yes, "Tune brand bass guitar" bought back some helpful results. The OP asked mentioned "brand", so I added that in my google search. Removing   "how to" from my search made it more helpful still. Look here for a Tune with an eerily similar headstock https://reverb.com/item/17834356-tune-tb-4-fretless-mod-see-thru-blue-free-shipping that I found with minimal searching. Hope this helps you, OP